# Wordpress Discord Preview

Tags: php, wordpress, discord

When working with wordpress what do you have to edit to change the preview display for uploading in a chat such as Discord.  Currently when posting a link it displays like this.

[image]

The preview is showing the site name, then author, then page name.  What do you have to change in wordpress to alter this?

Edit:
This code is in the page

```
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://kltools.net" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Twitch Kittens Tools" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Twitch Kittens Tools" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://kltools.net/wp-content/uploads/large_logo_only-1-150x150.png" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
```

Changing the display now to [image]

The last step here is I want to get rid of the author tag.

I've tried a plugin that is supposed to remove the author from php and css and it's still displaying.  Is there anything anyone can recommend to get rid of the author tag in the og meta preview

Comment: Presumably, this is completely dependent on the client as they can render it however they want. There is usually nothing you can do about it. However, I am unsure if this is the case with discord. (It most likely is)

Comment: Discord looks at any opengraph metadata on the site to generate its link previews. If you can alter the opengraph metadata, just do that.

Comment: I've done that, but it still is showing the author data.  I'm running a wordpress plugin that removes it and am unable to find any author data when viewing the source code that it would be using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to the functions.php file of your theme:

```
add_filter( 'oembed_response_data', 'disable_embeds_filter_oembed_response_data_' );
function disable_embeds_filter_oembed_response_data_( $data ) {
    unset($data['author_url']);
    unset($data['author_name']);
    return $data;
}
```